# Powershell: CheckBox.Add_CheckStateChanged

Tags: forms, powershell, checkbox

I've started with powershell forms and this is my first attempt.

I'd like to add more checkboxes and I've no problem with "CheckStateChanged". 
I'm looking for an alternative code with foreach declaration.
How can I shorten the code with my checkboxes using foreach x in y?

My first attempt works well:

```
$CheckBox1.Add_CheckStateChanged({
if ($CheckBox1.Checked){$CheckBox2.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox2.Enabled = $true}
if ($CheckBox1.Checked){$CheckBox3.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox3.Enabled = $true}
if ($CheckBox1.Checked){$CheckBox4.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox4.Enabled = $true}
})

$CheckBox2.Add_CheckStateChanged({
if ($CheckBox2.Checked){$CheckBox1.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox1.Enabled = $true}
if ($CheckBox2.Checked){$CheckBox3.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox3.Enabled = $true}
if ($CheckBox2.Checked){$CheckBox4.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox4.Enabled = $true}
})

$CheckBox3.Add_CheckStateChanged({
if ($CheckBox3.Checked){$CheckBox1.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox1.Enabled = $true}
if ($CheckBox3.Checked){$CheckBox2.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox2.Enabled = $true}
if ($CheckBox3.Checked){$CheckBox4.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox4.Enabled = $true}
})

$CheckBox4.Add_CheckStateChanged({
if ($CheckBox4.Checked){$CheckBox1.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox1.Enabled = $true}
if ($CheckBox4.Checked){$CheckBox2.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox2.Enabled = $true}
if ($CheckBox4.Checked){$CheckBox3.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox3.Enabled = $true}
})
```

An alternative I'm looking for might look like:

`CheckBox1.Add_CheckStateChanged({
if (CheckBox1.Checked){foreach CheckBox in $_.Enabled = $false} else {$CheckBox2.Enabled = true}`

Unfortunately I can't figure it out how to use a foreach function with checkboxes. I'd like to add more than ten checkboxes to my form.

Comment: You mention "a problem with `CheckStateChanged`". It's not clear whether something isn't working or if you just want shorter code.  If you're encountering an error or the code isn't doing what you expect please edit the question to add those details.

Comment: Thank you for you hint, I've updated my thread.

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is focused on improving working code, so you might get better answers from there.

Comment: You might find the Switch commandlet useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6

Comment: @vonPryz It would get closed in it's current form for lack of context though.

Comment: Have you considered using a [radio button group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-group-windows-forms-radiobutton-controls-to-function-as-a-set) (since your check boxes are all mutually exclusive anyways)?

Comment: I'd like to thank you all for your quick replies. This is my first powershell form. I don't know a lot about powershell forms but I've found a lot useful information at stackoverflow. I've read basic tutorials and I've seen incompleted snippets only. "Switch" is not what I've been looking for and don't like radio buttons. I've been looking for a loop like Theo's example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) that I too think you are better off using a radio button group.

However, if you want to have mutually exclusive checkboxes and shorten your code, you could do this:

```
# create a scriptblock to be used in every checkboxes CheckStateChanged event
$checkChange = {
    # loop through all the forms checkbox controls.
    # the sender object is captured in the automatic variable '$this'
    $form.Controls | Where-Object {$_ -is [System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox]} | ForEach-Object {
        # if this checkbox is checked, disable all others, otherwise
        # set all checkbox controls to Enabled
        $_.Enabled = if ($this.Checked) { ($_ -eq $this) } else { $true }
    }
}

# add the scriptblock to the individual checkbox objects
$CheckBox1.Add_CheckStateChanged($checkChange)
$CheckBox2.Add_CheckStateChanged($checkChange)
$CheckBox3.Add_CheckStateChanged($checkChange)
$CheckBox4.Add_CheckStateChanged($checkChange)
```

---

As per your comment, yes, it is possible to collect all checkbox controls in an array and use that to build the form. It may shorten your code, but makes it less readable at the same time. Here's an example:

```
$chkBoxes = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 4; $i++) {
    $dummy = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
    $dummy.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,(20 + $i * 20))
    # add more COMMON properties if need be.
    # individual properties need to be set on each box by index.
    # e.g. $chkBoxes[0].Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand

    # set the CheckStateChanged handler on the control
    $dummy.Add_CheckStateChanged($checkChange)
    # add the new control to the $chkBoxes array
    $chkBoxes += $dummy
}
# add the array of controls to the form
$form.Controls.AddRange($chkBoxes)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much for this snippet. It's exactly what I've been looking for. I've started with a basic form, I'm a pure beginner. This is a fantastic example:)

Comment: If this route is taken, would a next step be to put all buttons in an array?

Comment: Thank you very much for your second example. I prefer your first example because it's easier to understand for a beginner like me. I'll keep your second example in mind, it's a little bit too complicated for me.